# Explicit equations for morphism determined by a linear system, Part II

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is a follow-up to this question:
https://mathoverflow.net/q/234967/89715 . I realized my wording was a bit unclear and that I could have been more direct in what I was asking for.

Let me set up the notation once again, for the convenience of the reader. Consider $X = \mathbb{P}^2_k$ and $\mathcal{O}_X(2).$ If we consider the linear system $\mathcal{L}$ of conics passing through the point $[0:0:1]$ we can see that this is spanned by the sections $\{x^2,y^2,xy,yz,xz\}$ and that this linear system defines a rational map $f:X \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^4_k.$ Blowing up at the point $[0,0,1]$ we get a surface $p:\tilde{X} \rightarrow X.$ It is then possible to show that we have an extension of $f$ to a map $g: X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^4_k.$ I want to get an explicit description of this map, in terms of coordinates. Let me tell you my approach, and where I got stumped.

I consider the linear system $\mathcal{L}$ on $X$ generated by $\{x^2,y^2,xy,yz,xz\}$ and pull this back by $p:\tilde{X} \rightarrow X$ to get an invertible sheaf $p^\ast \mathcal{L}$ together with a linear system on $\tilde{X}.$ This new linear system has basepoints along the exceptional divisor $p^{-1}([0:0:1]) \cong \mathbb{P}^1_k.$ This corresponds to an effective Cartier divisor $D,$ so this suggests that we should be able to ''divide out'' by this on $p^\ast \mathcal{L}$ to get a base-point free system. I tried to write down, explicitly how the transformed linear system should look like but I got something that didn't seem to do what I wanted (i.e be base-point free). I would be very glad if someone could help me write down how the linear system would look like, and what corresponding invertible sheaf the linear system would live on. I would also be happy to see how they derived the result.

Comment: Maybe it was better to edit your last question than create a new one? At any rate, I added more comments to your last question.

Comment: Please do not add new questions when an edit will do the job!

Answer (score 1):

I thought what I said was explicit enough. Let me try again. $\widetilde{X}\subset \mathbb{P}^2\times\mathbb{P}^1=Y$, given by the equation $xu-yv=0$ where $x,y,z$ are coordinates in 2-space as you described and $u,v$ are that of $\mathbb{P}^1$. One can embed $Y$ in $\mathbb{P}^5$ by the map, $(xu,yu,zu, xv,yv,zv)$ (Segre). It is clear that the image of $\widetilde{X}$ is inside the hyperplane given by $T_0-T_4=0$, where $(T_0,\ldots, T_5)$ are the coordinates of $\mathbb{P}^5$.